# android studio Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/reflect/Types$WildcardTypeImpl;

Tags: android, firebase

I use firebase database, storage, auth and google cloud vision.

I got this error

```
Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/reflect/Types$WildcardTypeImpl;
```

I think that this project gradle conflicts

this is my gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*************************"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField 'String', 'API_KEY', '"**********************"'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev369-1.23.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:colorpicker:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //firebase 구글 로그인 원래 16.0.2
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'

    //    ++++++++ 2018.11.08 ++++++++
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.11'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.11'

    //////////
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:16.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What can I do? ;(
I think gradle has some problems, but I dont' know what to do. 
I put almost all codes found from googling
Help me :(

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseUI has transistive dependencies on Firebase and Google Play libraries.  It's important to specify a [compatible set of libraries](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies) in your build.

You are using the most recent versions of the Firebase libraries, but very old versions of FirbaseUI.  As a first step, make these changes to use a compatible version of FirebaseUI:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.2.1'
...
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.1'
```